# Labels on the left and inline names in pgfgantt

Tags: pgfgantt

I am trying to create what they EU calls a "gantt" chart for the purpose of a research proposal. To do this I need to have multiple elements in the same line with their labels inline, but also a label on the left. E.g.

```
Label: | |bar 1|             |bar 2|  |bar 3||
```

How can I achieve it using pgfgantt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a possible solution

```
\documentclass[ ]{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[ inline ]{   1   }{  25  }
\ganttgroup[inline=false,group/.style={draw=none, fill=none}]   {   group 1}{   2,0 }{  25,0    }
\ganttbar   {   Task 1}{    2,0 }{  6,0 }
\ganttbar   {   Task 2}{    8,0 }{  10,0    }
\ganttbar   {   Task 3}{    13,0    }{  25,0    }\\
\ganttgroup[inline=false,group/.style={draw=none, fill=none}]   {   group 2}{   2,0 }{  25,0    }
\ganttbar   {   Task 1}{    2,0 }{  8,0 }
\ganttbar   {   Task 2}{    10,0    }{  15,0    }
\ganttbar   {   Task 3}{    18,0    }{  25,0    }
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image]